# Get the ordered product size and color in order items admin grid in Magento 1.9.2

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I am showing a list of items ordered from all the orders from 'sales_flat_order_item table' in Magneto 1.9.2. I get the name, SKU, and all other values from the following collection.

```
protected function _prepareCollection() {
    $collection = Mage::getModel('sales/order_item')->getCollection();
    $collection->getSelect()->join(array('o' => 'sales_flat_order'), 'main_table.order_id = o.entity_id', array('increment_id','created_at'));
    $this->setCollection($collection);
    parent::_prepareCollection();
    return $this;
}
```

Now I want to get the size and color of the item ordered. I am new to Magento, so I have no clue where I can get these values from.

Answer (score 0):

You can access them in `sales_flat_order_item` table collection.

```
$data        = $collection->getData();
$optionsData = unserialize($data['product_options']);
echo "<pre>";print_r($optionsData); 
// check the [attributes_info] for the custom options
```

The data in `product_options` is serialized, so if you unserialize it you end up with something like below :

```
Array
(
    [info_buyRequest] => Array
        (
            [uenc] => aHR0cDovLzUwLjU2LjIxMy4xNTcvbWVuL3RlZXMta25pdHMtYW5kLXBvbG9zL2NoZWxzZWEtdGVlLTUxNC5odG1sP29wdGlvbnM9Y2FydA,,
            [product] => 409
            [related_product] => 
            [super_attribute] => Array
                (
                    [92] => 20
                    [180] => 80
                )
        [qty] => 6
        [return_url] => 
    )

[attributes_info] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [label] => Color
                [value] => Black
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [label] => Size
                [value] => S
            )

    )

[simple_name] => Chelsea Tee
[simple_sku] => mtk004
[product_calculations] => 1
[shipment_type] => 0
[giftcard_lifetime] => 
[giftcard_is_redeemable] => 0
[giftcard_email_template] => 
[giftcard_type] => 
)
```